# How can I return multiple matches from SecItemCopyMatching in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I want to support multiple accounts in my iOS app and I'm using the KeyChain to store credentials. I'm storing accounts with the same class (kSecClassGenericPassword) and attribute (kSecAttrService) but with a different username (kSecAttrAccount). This works fine and I can log in with the different usernames.

I now want to retrieve these usernames and this is where I'm running into problems. 
I define and execute my query as:

```
let objects = [kSecClassGenericPassword, "foo", kCFBooleanTrue,kSecMatchLimitAll]
let keys = [kSecClass,kSecAttrService kSecReturnAttributes,kSecMatchLimit]
let query = NSDictionary(objects: objects, forKeys: keys)
var dataTypeRef : Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &dataTypeRef)
```

But only one item is returned. My dataTypeRef is a **CFDictionary** whereas I expected it to be a **CFArray**.

According to the [Apple Docs on SecItemCopyMatching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching)

> By default, this function returns only the first match found. To obtain more than one matching item at a time, specify the search key **kSecMatchLimit** with a value greater than 1. The result will be an object of type **CFArrayRef** containing up to that number of matching items.

As you can see from my code I've done this but with no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary(object:keys:)`. Just use `[kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecAttrServer: "foo", ...]`

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to [Apple Doc on SecItemCopyMatching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching) the second parameter of this function is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>`.

Notice that this is information from the most recent documentation.

```
let keychainQuery: [NSObject: AnyObject] =  [
    kSecClass : kSecClassInternetPassword,
    kSecReturnAttributes : kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecMatchLimit : kSecMatchLimitAll
]

var result: AnyObject?
let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&result) {
    SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}

if status == noErr {
    print(result)
}
```

I'm currently using this is in a project and it works great.

Hope that can helps you.